# Expected value of multiplication of matrices

Tags: random-variables, expected-value

While reading through [Xu et al. (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05980) I stumbled upon this proof:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Wyy^\intercal W^\intercal] & = \mathbb{E}[Wyy^\intercal W^\intercal-W\mathbb{E}[y]\mathbb{E}[y]^\intercal W^\intercal]+\mathbb{E}[W\mathbb{E}[y]\mathbb{E}[y]^\intercal W^\intercal]\\\
 & = \mathbb{E}[Wvar(y)W^\intercal]+\mathbb{E}[W\mathbb{E}[y]\mathbb{E}[y]^\intercal W^\intercal]\\
\end{align}$$

where $W$ and $y$ are independent.

What I don't get is how the first term becomes $\mathbb{E}[Wvar(y)W^\intercal]$. Sure it has to do with $var(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2]-(EX)^2$, but I just don't see what are the steps to make it so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
E[Wyy^⊺W^⊺−WE[y]E[y]^⊺W^⊺] = 
E[W ( yy^⊺ −  E[y]E[y]^⊺  ) W^⊺] =
E[W] \cdot E[ yy^⊺ −  E[y]E[y]^⊺ ] \cdot E[W^⊺]
$$

The last equality follows from the fact that $W$ and $y$ are independent.

But we have that, for a random vector $y$, by definition $ var(y) = E[yy^T ]- E[y] E[y]^T$.

So
$$
E[W]  \cdot  E[(yy^⊺−E[y]E[y]^⊺)]  \cdot E[W^⊺] = E[W] \cdot var(y) \cdot E[W^T] = E[W var(y) W^T].
$$
and we are done.